# Get GridView Cell Value Knowing Row And Column Index Only

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I think my question title is quite straight forward.

Any help is appreciated..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With BoundField and in readonly mode you can use `GridView1.Rows[x].Cells[x].Text` but with edit mode you have to use Controls collection to get reference of a control. This method returns a `Control` object.

```
Control control=GridView1.Rows[x].Cells[x].Controls[0]; // later you may cast it to appropriate control class.
```

If template field is used then you have to issue `FindControl` method from the `Cells` collection to get reference of a control based upon its `ID`. You may also use `Cells[x].Controls` collection too.

```
Control control=GridView1.Rows[x].Cells[x].FindControl("ID_Of_Control"); // later you may cast it to appropriate control class.
```

EDIT:

It is also possible that there can be one or more controls having same name/ID across the Templatefields. In that case you can't use `FindControl` method.

Example:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Now to get Button and change its text from 2nd row and 1st cell:

```
 Button btn = GridView1.Rows[1].Cells[0].Controls[1] as Button ;
 if(btn!=null)
    btn.Text = "Hello";
```

Comment: Hey, thx but I actually applied this code before and it's not working... I am using template field fyi... any alternative?

Comment: @Rofans.NET - There are two ways to get controls from TemplateField cell - FindControl method and Controls collection.

Comment: @AVD: and `FindControl` finds the control without prociding the cell index, right?

Answer (score 3):

If it's a BoundField you could do

```
gv.Rows[1].Cells[1].Text;
```

If it's a TemplateField, you have to get the control that has the value you want.

```
Label L = gv.Rows[1].FindControl("yourcontrolId") as Label;
L.Text;
```

Comment: I did try this code.. but it's not working... any alternative?

Comment: Is it a TemplateField or a BoundField?

Comment: @Rofans.NET - check my edit - you need to grab the control that you want to read using FindControl

Comment: Nope not working fyi I do something like this:  " Label box = (Label)(gvGridView.Rows[index].Cells[0].FindControl(Table.Columns[0].ColumnName)); "

Comment: FindControl takes the **id** of the control you're looking for

Comment: If its a templatefield, you could omit `Cells[1]` altogether

Comment: @Rofans.NET: the above snippet should work. please do not just tell "its not working". it wont help any of us. please elaborate on what exactly happened when you tried that. whether you got an error... whats your control type...

Comment: This worked as explained originally. I don't know what you're problem is @rofansmanao