# How to Export into Excel from Gridview

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

I have a button to Export my Gridview1 data to Excel, but when i tried the code below(which i used in C#), it gives me a compiling error.  Can you help me..

Error 1: Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView'

Error 2: The name 'MessageBox' does not exist in the current context

```
try
        {
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            excel.Visible = true;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook workbook = excel.Workbooks.Add(System.Reflection.Missing.Value);
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet sheet1 = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)workbook.Sheets[1];
            int StartCol = 1;
            int StartRow = 1;
            int j = 0, i = 0;

            //Write Headers
            for (j = 0; j < GridView1.Columns.Count; j++)
            {
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range myRange = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)sheet1.Cells[StartRow, StartCol + j];
                myRange.Value2 = GridView1.Columns[j].HeaderText;
            }

            StartRow++;

            //Write datagridview content
            for (i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                for (j = 0; j < GridView1.Columns.Count; j++)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range myRange = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)sheet1.Cells[StartRow + i, StartCol + j];
                        myRange.Value2 = GridView1[j, i].Value == null ? "" : GridView1[j, i].Value;
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        ;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
```

Comment: if its a web site then MessageBox.Show() won't work, its a win form control

Comment: it will i added this
 
using System.Windows.Forms;

Comment: You can add the using statement but it's still not going to work when you run it

Comment: thanks, i converted it into alert syntax.. hope you can help me with my another problem in exporting gridview data into excel, though it runs but the exported file has no data within.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, full disclosure: I'm not an expert on asp.net WebForms, so I'm reading this on a syntax basis only (not examining whether or not your actual framework usage is correct).

### Error 1

To my eye, the error occurs here:

```
myRange.Value2 = GridView1[j, i].Value == null ? "" : GridView1[j, i].Value;
```

It looks like you are trying to reference `GridView1` with array notation, inside a loop using variables `i` and `j`. However, look at your loops:

```
for (i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)

for (j = 0; j < GridView1.Columns.Count; j++)
```

Your loops are accessing `GridView1` via collections, specifically `.Rows` and `.Columns` respectively. So my assumption would be that you might need something like:

```
myRange.Value2 = GridView1.Rows[i].Columns[j].Value == null ? "" : GridView1.Rows[i].Columns[j].Value;
```

Remember, this is just a syntactic guess based on your earlier code (`GridView1.Columns[j].HeaderText`).

### Error 2

The issue here is that the name (static class or variable) you are using, `MessageBox`, doesn't seem to exist at this point in the code. So I would ask:

1. Is the variable in scope? I.e., is it declared earlier in the `try` block, and has now gone out of scope in the `catch`?
2. If it's a static class, is the assembly referenced correctly? Intellisense should pick this up for you in Visual Studio, with refactor options to include a reference as a `using` statement above, or fully qualify the name for you.

From memory `MessageBox` is a static class in the `WPF` assemblies somewhere to do with windows forms, **not** as a part of ASP.NET - it is used to show a window in a desktop program. If you wish to show a message in a browser, that would be a javascript statement like:

```
alert("Your exception message here");
```

However, you will need some means of catching that Exception (`ex`), grabbing the text from it (`ex.ToString()`) and transmitting that into the page to be shown via javascript.

**Last thought on that:** if you are wanting to show that error, and it's as a result of a button clicked on the page, you may be intending to invoke the Export to Excel function as an AJAX call to the server. If this is the case, try returning a HTTP error code (like a 500 or something) back to the browser, and using the `.fail()` binder to display an appropriate client-side error. Just a suggestion :)

Comment: i made some adjustments on your script to eliminate compile error: it runs but the problem now is no data were exported in the Excel file.

myRange.Value2 = GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j] == null ? "" : GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Text;

Comment: i think the problem leaves here, 
myRange.Value2 = GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j] == null ? "" : GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Text; i tried this and no data exported from the gridview.

Comment: To be honest I'm not 100% sure - the question was around your syntax and compile errors, *not* around the `GridView`. However, check out this related post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8640532/get-gridview-cell-value-knowing-row-and-column-index-only - looks like you need to use the `.Text` property of the `GridView` if you are in display mode, or possibly find a control, depending on your page code.